# Include square brackets in posting from jsp

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags

Can we post square brackets in parameter name of a text area field in html/jsp? I am trying to post a jsp array like `<textarea name = "arr['$i']">`and variable `i` has `[]` in them. So what is the best way to encode them in a way that I can post them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not required to pass it as squarebracket and generate a unique id. Note: $i is not applicable in JSP for a variable. The getParameter() indeed returns only the first one when there are multiple values on the same name. You need to use getParameterValues() instead to get all of those values.

```
<textarea name="txtarea">Content 1 </textarea>
<textarea name="txtarea">Content 2 </textarea>
```

String[] txtareaids = request.getParameterValues("txtarea");